# split simple string on multiple characters in java code

Tags: java

i have a text `http://icons/image.png?_=1520236903874` and it is variable and i want to extract `image.png` from the text

My trail:

```
.split("/|?")
```

but it doesn't give me the desired output ... any help ??

Comment: `split("/|\\?")` ... question mark is a regex metacharacter, and needs to be escaped if you mean it literally.  But why not use a URL API which can already extract the various components of a URL?

Comment: Please clarify. You want the last part of a URL path? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I tested this at myregextester.com and this regex is working:

```
.*\/(.+\..+)\?
```

The provided code is the following:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
class Module1{
  public static void main(String[] asd){
  String sourcestring = "http://icons/image.png?_=1520236903874";
  Pattern re = Pattern.compile(".*\\/(.+\\..+)\\?");
  Matcher m = re.matcher(sourcestring);
  int mIdx = 0;
  while (m.find()){
    for( int groupIdx = 0; groupIdx < m.groupCount()+1; groupIdx++ ){
      System.out.println( "[" + mIdx + "][" + groupIdx + "] = " + m.group(groupIdx));
    }
    mIdx++;
  }
}
}
```